# How to clone and print data in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table which prints data from a JSON. Every row have an delete option. 
I want to print the deleted data into a new table. I have managed to print data in console but unable to add it into view.
Below is the code:

Controller

```
    $scope.deletedItems = [];
    var counter = 0

    $scope.removeRow = function (idx) {
       console.log(idx);        
       $scope.TTNdata.splice(idx, 1);       
       var deletedArray = $scope.TTNdata.slice(idx, 1); 
       //console.log(deletedArray);
       $scope.deletedItems.push(deletedArray);
       console.log($scope.deletedItems);
       counter++;
       $('#counter').html(counter); 
    };
```

View:

```
 <table id="deleted-rows" class="">
    <thead>
        <th>Sr. No</th>
        <th>ID</th>         
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Second Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Remove</th>

    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in deletedItems | orderBy:'id'">
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td>{{item.id}} </td>
        <td>{{item.first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.last_name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.gender}}</td>
        <td><a href="mailto:'{{data.email}}'">{{item.email}}</a></td>
        <td><img src="{{item.photo}}" alt="{{item.first_name}} {{item.last_name}} photo"></td>
        <td class=""> <span style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="removeRow($index)" title="Remove Record" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></td>       
    </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Sr. No</th>
        <th>ID</th>         
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Second Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Remove</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in TTNdata | filter:bindtext | orderBy:'id'">
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td>{{data.id}} </td>
        <td>{{data.first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.last_name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.gender}}</td>
        <td><a href="mailto:'{{data.email}}'">{{data.email}}</a></td>
        <td><img src="{{data.photo}}" alt="{{data.first_name}} {{data.last_name}} photo"></td>
        <td class=""> <span style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="removeRow($index)" title="Remove Record" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></td>       
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Data is printing in console but not in table, every time i click remove it will generate a blank row in deleted table
What I am doing wrong?

Code on github https://github.com/sahilpopli/learningAngular.git

Comment: What stops you from doing `$('.someClass').html($scope.deletedItems);` ?

Comment: Can you add jsfiddle link?

Comment: @xaternev i have tried this but not worked

Comment: @Xatenev This is Angularjs related question, so your solution in this specific case wouldn't be considered as a good practice

Comment: @AlonEitan he already used jquery to set his counter so he can aswell continue using jquery to set other content.

Answer (score 0):

`slice` returns array, so try `$scope.deletedItems.push(deletedArray[0]);`

Or try to concatenate the arrays by doing so: `$scope.deletedItems = $scope.deletedItems.concat(deletedArray);`

Answer (score 0):

A possible thing that you may need to think is that if you going to have paged tables, removing the object from a list with that index could not be a good thing.

My solution to your problem would be this(using the id instead of index). This is just scratch demonstrating a possible way to achieve what is your desire.

**Code**

```
angular.module('App', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.List = [{
      Id: 1,
      Name: 'Name1'
    }, {
      Id: 2,
      Name: 'Name2'
    }, {
      Id: 3,
      Name: 'Name3'
    }];
    $scope.newList = [];

    var remove = function(itemId) {
      var indexS = $scope.List.filter(function(item, index) {
        return item.Id == itemId;
      });
      if (indexS.length == 1)
        $scope.newList.push($scope.List.splice($scope.List.indexOf(indexS[0]), 1)[0])
    };

    $scope.removeMe = remove;
  }]);
```

**Markup**

```
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<table>
  <thead>
    <th> Id </th>
    <th> Name </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in List">
      <td >{{item.Id}}</td>
      <td >{{item.Name}}</td>
      <td ng-click="removeMe(item.Id)">removeme</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th> Id </th>
    <th> Name </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in newList">
      <td >{{item.Id}}</td>
      <td >{{item.Name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0YQcM4bBoKa3S2MoLuAT?p=preview)